# can't uninstall Python 3.6 on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, python, uninstall

I installed python 3.6.2 recently on my windows 10 machine, but I cannot seem to uninstall it at all

The error I get is:

[image]

> No python 3.6 installation was detected

then

> 0x800070643 Fatal error during installation

Things I tried

- c:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python > delete folder, app still shows up
- Revo uninstaller > uninstall python 3.6
- Uninstall app normally through "add or remove" programs
- Delete Python36 environmental path
- Some combinastion of repair+modify and then uninstall... no go

How do I fix this?

I haven't tried doing any registry edits or using restore points yet though

Comment: Have you tried install and then uninstall?

Comment: ya I can't install either now since it can't find my installation, and I can't uninstall since it can't find my installation

Comment: This was an irritating one that I got as well, for me I had to delete program cache folder in C:\User\username\AppData\Local\Windows\Microsoft\Program Cache. The good tool that helped me find any file or folder (and it's path) related to the python installation that had the issue, was fzf. It's a fuzzy finder, a linux tool, but you can install it easily using the package manager scoop i.e scoop install fzf. Though I don't exactly remember which bucket it was exactly in so as a precautionary, prior to installation you could do - scoop bucket add main & scoop bucket add extras. Hope this helps.

Comment: After searching tons of misleading posts I found it easier to just find the windows installler and install over the top of the existing folder structure. Luckily I still was able to find a Windows 3.9.0 installer in the downloads folder. Now the Python appeared in the Uninstall programs. What a palaver!

Answer (score 30):

Solution:

UNHIDE ALL FOLDERS BEFORE FOLLOWING DOWN...

1. Go to C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Programs
2. **Delete** Python Folder
3. Go to Control Panel >> **Uninstall a Program**
4. Right Click on Python and then **Change/Modify**
5. Click on **Repair** Python. **Note: This may or may not fail, but be patient**
6. Now Again go to step 3
7. Now, after step 3, uninstall Python

Congratulations!! Uninstalled!!

Now Install a new fresh version

Happy Coding! Happy Programming!!

Comment: I tried these steps, and it broke my install/uninstall. Luckily I had saved a zip archive of the folder before deleting it. A normal uninstall worked for me without issue. First try a normal uninstall, before trying these steps.

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez I find it fun that you searched and applied a solution for a problem you didn't have.

Comment: What if python does not show up in the list of uninstallable programs?

Answer (score 8):

It's also possible to execute the python3 installer again, you get option to repair or uninstall. Just choose uninstall, it will be done properly.

Answer (score 1):

I just used a restore point didn't have to edit registry

Comment: That's a terrible solution, (I'm not blaming you but windows)

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled first which removed it from the list but none of the files.
Go to the folder and delete and then delete from the start menu - seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you got here because of this annoying message when trying to install a Python package because Python was installed by Windows (likely by Visual Studio), then you might want to keep reading...

> WARNING: The script virtualenv.exe is installed in
> 'C:\Users{user}\AppData...\Python...\Scripts' which is not on PATH

Before you uninstall using the steps below, please read the beginning of my answer here first!!!!!!!!  know the consequences!  If your other Python environments rely on this, you might have to fix a few other things, so run a few commands and get the current details.  You will only be able to install packages if you have the required set up, without having a site or global Python install.

```
pip config -v list
pip show virtualenv
```

Read this before the uninstall and know what you're getting into.

https://www.dummies.com/programming/python/how-to-find-path-information-in-python/

After you study a bit, you can uninstall from here.  Merry Christmas!

Control Panel > Settings > Apps > Apps & features > use the Filter by menu, and select the drive containing the "WindowsApps" folder > Select the app and click the Uninstall button > Click the Uninstall button again

Answer (score 0):

I rd /q/s everything python.. ended up being registry even on 'repair ...'

HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-21-507921405-113007714-1801674531-941164\Components

maybe also something in user folder .... \Python\Launcher\ but I think it was the registry ...

to clarify ...
run in a command prompt run

dir/s/b *python*
then run this on every folder found
rd /q/s  c:\python_doesnotknowhowtomakeainstaller

then open the registry and look for the key above and replace the SSID with yours S-1-5-21-507921405-113007714-1801674531-941164

or just look for the word python in the registry and delete everything you find ...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1128271)